IntelliJ display execution time of each line
It would be incredibly useful if there was a function in IntelliJ that would display the last execution time for each line in the editor.
For example, if I run the program in debug mode, each time a line of code is executed, IntelliJ displays how long it took to execute that line in milliseconds.
await User.init();               // 2ms
await Sett.initialize();         // 10ms
await Workspace.initialize();    // 21ms
await SystemStore.initialize();  // 2ms

Is there something like this, or maybe a plugin? (I don't know if this is important but I'm using the programming language Dart.)

Please don't post images of code. Copy and paste the code and use comments to add that extra info.

You can submit feature request on Jetbrains website, not here. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA

@MikkelT I was not asking about a feature request but if this feature is already available.

I found out that Dart DevTools can do this, however it can't display it directly in the line.
